# Background image in MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django

I want to let the admin users modify the background image of the main site. Base.html includes a css file where the background image is set.

I made a view in the admin where people can upload a file. It is then saved in MEDIA_ROOT/static/img/background.jpg . The plan is to then run collectstatic with STATICFILES_DIRS containing MEDIA_ROOT/static . Is it good practice? If not, what would be a preferred solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not save/serve this image in/from MEDIA_ROOT without staticfiles?

Comment: Wouldnt there be a cache issue with the site users only getting the new image when their browser cached is emptied?

Comment: There is no difference between serving files from MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL.  You can set expiration time for individual file in your web-server config.

Comment: How would you specify from the css code where to find the background image contained in MEDIA ?

Comment: In your case just add one level up: '../../background.jpg' or '../../img/background.jpg'